# Number of twenty one digit numbers such that Product of the digits is divisible by $21$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of twenty one digit numbers such that Product of the digits is divisible by $21$

Since product is divisible by $21$ the number should contain the digits $3,6,7,9$ But i am unable to decide how to proceed...can i have any hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the product of the digits divisible by $21$ you just need (at least one of $3,6,$ or $9$ and at least one $7$) or at least one $0$.  Compute how many numbers do not meet this criterion and subtract from all the numbers.  How many $21$ digit numbers do not include a $7$?  How many include no $3,6,9$?  What happens with the ones that have neither of these?  How many have no $0$?

Answer (score 2):

So Number of numbers without digit $7$ and digit $0$ but atleast one of $3,6,9$ is $X$

number of numbers without $3,6,9,0$ but atleast one $7$ is $Y$

Number of numbers without $3,6,9,7,0$ is $5^{21}$

Hence total numbers are $$10^{21}-(X+Y+5^{21})$$